# book for iphone game programming

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if someone could suggest me some good books for developing iPhone games applications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I'm wary of Games Programming books. I find it better to learn from a normal programming book, and apply what you learn into games. Then you can use the Game Programming book as more of a reference.

I use this:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-iPhone-Games-Development-Professionals/dp/1430225998/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1296645855&sr=1-1-spell

But I learned iOS from this:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-iPhone-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430224592/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_c

Answer (score 0):

I dont kow much about books on iphone game programming but i have come across some open source game engines sites that help in making iphone games .These are http://www.sparrow-framework.org/ and http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/